# How do I fill the remaining space with lis in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL

```
+-- -+----------+
| id | whatever |
+----+----------+
| 1  |  blah1   |
+----+----------+
| 1  |  blah2   |
+----+----------+
| 1  |  blah3   |
+----+----------+
```

PHP

```
echo '<ul>'

$a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '1' LIMIT 10");
while($b = mysql_fetch_assoc($a))
{
    echo '<li>'.$b['whatever'].'</li>';
}

echo '</ul>';
```

Output:

```
<ul>
    <li>blah1</li>
    <li>blah2</li>
    <li>blah3</li>
</ul>
```

However, what I want to do is fill the remaining space (in the case above) with **7 empty lis**.

So, the output should be:

```
<ul>
    <li>blah1</li>
    <li>blah2</li>
    <li>blah3</li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Tangential: If `id` is a numeric column, do not put single quotes around values you compare/assign it to in queries. MySQL will convert it to a number, but that doesn't always result in the same thing as if you had written a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo '<ul>'

$a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '1' LIMIT 10");
while($b = mysql_fetch_assoc($a))
{
    echo '<li>'.$b['whatever'].'</li>';
}

for ($i = mysql_num_rows($a); $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo '<li></li>';
}

echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the number of rows beforehand (`mysql_num_rows`), then write your li's `10-rows` times.